# Update multiple rows from select statement

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to assign 'A' to [Student Details].group based on this SELECT statement.

```
SELECT     TOP (10) PERCENT [Person Id], [Given Names], Surname, Gpa, [Location Cd]
FROM         [Student Details]
WHERE     ([Location Cd] = 'PAR')
ORDER BY Gpa DESC
```

I can't figure out how to use a SELECT statement in an UPDATE statement.
Can someone please explain how to accomplish this?

I am using ASP .NET and MsSQL Server if it makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Comment: Do you need to update the table or just a select with `'A'` as group?

Comment: Currently Group is null.. I need to update group to contain 'A' for all of the rows that are returned from the above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `CTE` (Common Table Expression):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [Group]
    FROM      [Student Details]
    WHERE     ([Location Cd] = 'PAR')
    ORDER BY Gpa DESC
)
UPDATE CTE SET [Group] = 'A'
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting incorrect syntax near GROUP and FROM :(

Comment: There is no syntax error as far as I can see. [Check this similar example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/046e1/3) with no such syntax errors. May be you are missing angle brackets `'[]'` around group which is a key word.

Comment: ah you're a champion, the problem was that there was 2 of the word BY :)
Apart from that, it worked :D

Thank you.

Comment: Early morning hear and the engine is still warming up ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to update these records and then return them :

```
SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT [Person Id], [Given Names], Surname, Gpa, [Location Cd]
INTO #temp
FROM [Student Details]
WHERE     ([Location Cd] = 'PAR')
ORDER BY Gpa DESC

update [Student Details] set group='A' where [person id] in(select [person id] from #temp)

select * from #temp
```

I'm also assuming person id is the PK of student details

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
Update top (10) Percent [Student Details] set [group] = 'A' 
where [Location Cd] = 'PAR' AND [group] is null
```

Comment: No sorry, it must sort the rows based on GPA and only assign group='A' to the top 10%
Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Sorry still wouldn't work.. It needs to sort the table in descending order from the column 'gpa'